# Terraform SDK - Custom Provider - how to accept JSON input in data source?

Tags: terraform

As far as I can tell, the Terraform SDK does not support an interface type. In my case I'm using a data resource to reach out to an API and pull JSON data. I would like to put that data in an attribute for later use in a resource but the problem is the JSON response has a large dictionary filled with different types. In GoLang this is no problem because you can set the map type to `Interface{}`. It would seem however that terraform only allows you to set the following types in a schema:

- TypeInt
- TypeString
- TypeBool
- TypeFloat
- TypeInvalid
- TypeList
- TypeMap

Without support for interface how would you go about doing this correctly? The very ugly hack I have right now is converting everything to a string and then fixing the type once it is passed to the resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked on Hashicorp's forums and received a phenomenal answer [here](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/how-to-handle-json-input-into-data-resource-with-multiple-types-with-the-terraform-sdk/22896/2).

The synopsis is that casting to a string is currently the best solution. However there is a team working on making a new SDK design which would support newer capabilities to include arguments with dynamically chosen types.